# SQL wildcard for date parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, wildcard

I have a stored procedure with a single parameter `@date`

The procedure is a `select` statement which contains:

`where dateTimeGmt between @date and dateadd(dd,9,@date)`

I'd like to be able to call this procedure and get all the results using all the dates within the table.

Setting `@date` to `%` or `NULL` or `%-%-%` doesn't work.

Is there an elegant way of having the procedure ignore that `where` clause if no parameter is passed with the `exec`?

Comment: `WHERE dateTimeGmt between @date AND dateadd (dd, 9, @date) OR @date IS NULL` should do the trick

Comment: You may want to read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to call this procedure and get all the results
>   using all the dates within the table.
>
> Setting @date to % or NULL or %-%-% doesn't work.

% comparision only works for string types, not with dates

> Is there an elegant way of having the procedure ignore that where
>   clause if no parameter is passed with the exec?

Try changing your where clause as following.

```
where (dateTimeGmt between @date and dateadd(dd,9,@date) ) or @date  IS NULL
```

Comment: How does this work? NULL is NULL returns everything, so why does a date still return a subset when its an OR? And between NULL and NULL returns nothing, in which case NULL is NULL returns everything. Is there a good breakdown of the logic?

Comment: If you pass a value to date parameter, first part of the condition will return true if the row date is between the defined date so (true or false => true), if not then first part is false so (false or false => false) It will not return the row. For the second case when date parameter is null the second part is always true so that (false or true =>true) for every row and it will return each row of the query.